# Hand-Held Electronic Body Scanners on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, army-military-war

Can hand held electronic body scanners be used by synagogue volunteers on Shabbat for security purposes? This is in response to terrorist threats against American (specifically American-Jewish) targets as well as recent anti-Semitic attacks against American-Jewish institutions.

Comment: Are you asking about scanners in particular and only, or are you asking about all security equipment (e.g., radios, cameras, writing implements, firearms)?  BTW, the security posts at the kotel are staffed on Shabbat.  I presume they use scanners on Shabbat as during the week.

Comment: If we're really at the point where using body scanners is pikuach nefesh, maybe it would be preferable to not violate shabbos and have everybody daven in yichidus. This might depend partially on whether using electricity is considered a deoraita or derabanan prohibition although I don't know of any cases where davening in a minyan at the expense of even a derabanan shabbos violation is preferred.

Comment: Wouldn't the best case just be to have non-Jews manning the body scanners?

Comment: @Daniel, nobody said anything about the volunteers' being Jewish.

Comment: @msh210 True. I assumed that's what the OP meant by "synagogue volunteers" but you're right that it doesn't have to mean that.

Comment: @Daniel ".. daven in yichidus." - Understood. But, a "happier" solution would be to make minyanim in people's homes, and that allows for the weekly parsha to be read. When I lived in Kew Garden Hills (NY), I went to a shul that looked like a small house. After being there for about 4 years, someone asked the Rav why he never placed a sign in front saying this was a shul. His answer was "brilliant". "Why do I need to attract attention? Those who know who what and where we are, are the only ones that need to find us!" W/ Mazal even with a door open 24 hours, B"H, no one ever robbed the shul!

Comment: The volunteers are Jews and the question is specific to scanners that are charged prior to Shabbat. The synagogue in question is high profile. Thank you.